# React native: remove item from ListView based on state for not logged users

Tags: list, react-native

I am new to RN, and I am trying to show/hide an item in a List based on logged user state.

I have achieved the goal to hide the item on logout, but still have problem on the login part.

I am using *react-native-elements* and especially the *SideMenu* component.

I have created two arrays as you can see below.

Here is my arrays:

```
var listLogged = [
   {
     name        : 'Page 1'
   },
   {
     name        : 'Page 2'
   },
   {
     name        : 'Logout'
   }];

 var listNotLogged = [
   {
     name        : 'Page 1'
   },
   {
     name        : 'Page 2'
   }];
```

In the render:

```
if (this.state.LoggedIn) {
<List>
{
 listLogged.map((item, j) => (
   <ListItem
    key={j}
    title={item.name}
   />
 ))
}
</List>
} else {
<List>
{
  listNotLogged.map((item, j) => (
    <ListItem
     key={j}
     title={item.name}
    />
   ))
}
</List>
```

But unfortunately I do not know how and where set the state, the main problem is that the Menu component is already rendered before the login.

Hope in some help! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `<List />` component is inside of a `React Component`, you can use `this.setState({ LoggedIn: true })` to change the state, and the `render()` function will automatically re-run.

I've whipped up an example below to show you how tapping a "Log In" button can change the state, which causes `render()` to re-run with the new state and produce a different outcome. Tapping `Logout` will toggle the state back:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { List, ListItem, SideMenu, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

const list = [  
  { name: 'Page 1', onPress: null },
  { name: 'Page 2', onPress: null }
];

class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { LoggedIn: false };
  }

  toggleLoggedInState = () => {
    this.setState({ LoggedIn: !this.state.LoggedIn });
  }

  render() {
    let button;
    if (this.state.LoggedIn) {
      list.push({ name: 'Logout', onPress: this.toggleLoggedInState });
      button = <Button title="Log In" onPress={this.toggleLoggedInState} />;
    }

    const items = list.reduce((array, item) => {
      array.push(
        <ListItem
          key={j}
          title={item.name}
          onPress={item.onPress)
        />
      );
      return array;
    }, []);

    return (
      <SideMenu>
        <List>
          {items}
        </List>
        {button}
      </SideMenu>
    )
  }
}

export default Example;
```

If you want to change the state elsewhere and have this view respond, you'd be better off using something like [redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) under the hood. That gives you an underlying `state` for your whole app.

Comment: Unfortunately I have this problem: `array.push()` is not a function, and I don't know why!

Comment: @Mark I've updated the code... I wasn't passing in an empty array at the end of the `reduce()` function.